# Trying to receive messages from a publish/subscribe socket in the background with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, zeromq, publish-subscribe, python-multithreading

I'm working on a tank battle AI and as such, I'm trying to create a function that constantly updates the map and player information in the background by receiving messages from a socket with a **`PUB`**/**`SUB`** formal-pattern.

**`comm`** is a communication object in my main client.

This `movement_strategy()` function is called from another module, but I keep getting an error:

> `Exception in thread Thread-1, ZMQError: Socket operation on non-socket.`

Any ideas on what's causing it or how to fix it?

```
import communication
import gamestate
import json
import threading
import time

def movement_strategy(comm):

    def get_gamestate():
        [token, msg] = comm.pub_socket.recv_multipart()
        msg = json.loads(msg)
        if msg["comm_type"] == "GAMESTATE":
            game_info = gamestate.GameState( msg["comm_type"],
                                             msg["timestamp"],
                                             msg["timeRemaining"],
                                             msg["map"],
                                             msg["players"]
                                             )
            print game_info.timeRemaining
            print game_info.timestamp
        time.sleep(1)


    thread = threading.Thread(target=get_gamestate, args())
    thread.start()
```

Comment: First of all, hard to say anything with any certainty without seeing where you instantiate the socket. Secondly, however, ZMQ sockets are not thread safe. I've read that Python has some magic in the GIL that makes it work appropriately, so it might work sometimes for you, but I don't believe that's been proven to be reliable behavior. So, you should only instantiate a socket within the thread that it's going to be used unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: You might want to know, that StackOverflow encourages users to post a so called an **MCVE** -- a **M** -inimum **C** -omplete **V** -erifiable **E** -xample of code ( + data, where necessary ) that reproduces the problem under review. Also claiming an error without a context-full Exception trace is not a welcome practice on StackOverflow - you ask people to help you, so providing no details yields in low chances to get more. **Anyway, enjoy this great Community of Knowledge.**